# cURL works, but an identical request in Apache's HttpComponents library does not?

Tags: java, php, curl, apache-httpcomponents

I have literally been tearing my hair out for days over this one little issue. Hopefully, someone here can spot my mistake (because I'm sure it's on my end) and give me a few points on how to remedy it. If I fail at my explanation, let me know and I'll try to rewrite it in a more succinct manner.

--

A bit of background: as part of a small side project, I've been writing a Java application to monitor chat and event data sent out by an in-browser game (for reference; [Command & Conquer: Tiberium Alliances](http://www.tiberiumalliances.com/home)). Sadly, there isn't much documentation on how their web service works, but I've managed to piece together a series of requests (based on watching network traffic and from code samples posted by other developers) to handle logging in and such.

One particular request absolutely refuses to complete, and Java is throwing a connection reset exception after pausing for 30 seconds. Below is the connection log for this particular request.

```
 2014/03/25 11:17:16:703 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
 2014/03/25 11:17:16:703 EDT [DEBUG] RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
 2014/03/25 11:17:16:703 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://gamecdnorigin.alliances.commandandconquer.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
 2014/03/25 11:17:16:703 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 2][route: {s}->https://gamecdnorigin.alliances.commandandconquer.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 2 of 20]
 2014/03/25 11:17:16:703 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Opening connection {s}->https://gamecdnorigin.alliances.commandandconquer.com:443
 2014/03/25 11:17:16:755 EDT [DEBUG] HttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to gamecdnorigin.alliances.commandandconquer.com/212.100.228.211:443
 *snip: 30 seconds of junk output*
 2014/03/25 11:18:16:992 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-2: Shutdown connection
 2014/03/25 11:18:16:992 EDT [DEBUG] MainClientExec - Connection discarded
 2014/03/25 11:18:16:993 EDT [DEBUG] DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-2: Close connection
 2014/03/25 11:18:16:993 EDT [DEBUG] PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 2][route: {s}->https://gamecdnorigin.alliances.commandandconquer.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
 2014/03/25 11:18:16:993 EDT [INFO] RetryExec - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://gamecdnorigin.alliances.commandandconquer.com:443: Connection reset
 2014/03/25 11:18:16:993 EDT [DEBUG] RetryExec - Connection reset <java.net.SocketException: Connection reset>java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
 *snip: lots of extra backtrace*
```

It's a lot, I know :/

The strange part is, running the EXACT same request using PHP's cURL works just fine, and I get back the information I would expect to. Below is the code snippets for both the Java that is sending the failing request, as well as the PHP that is completing successfully.

**Java:**

```
public static boolean loadWorlds(Session session) {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://gamecdnorigin.alliances.commandandconquer.com/Farm/Service.svc/ajaxEndpoint/GetOriginAccountInfo");
    HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(String.format("{\"session\":\"%s\"}", session.getId()), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    post.setHeader("X-Qooxdoo-Response-Type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    post.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    post.setEntity(entity);

    try {
        CloseableHttpResponse resp = ApiCommunicator.getHttpClient().execute(post);

        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

**cURL via PHP:**

```php
<?php
    $cookie = 'cookies/' . md5($user) . '.txt';
    $data = array(
        'session' => 'hidden :P'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gamecdnorigin.alliances.commandandconquer.com/Farm/Service.svc/ajaxEndpoint/GetOriginAccountInfo');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "X-Qooxdoo-Response-Type: application/json"
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

In an effort to keep this post as short as possible (since it's already a painfully long wall of text) I rewrote the PHP slightly to show the values of $cookie and $data, since both are set further up in the script's execution.

Any help at all would be appreciated. I have no idea if HttpComponents adds or removes header data to requests (I literally just started learning the library 2 days ago when I picked up this project) that cURL would not. If necessary, I can post more code samples, since there's nothing in this project that's really "secret" other than things like my personal logins / session information that's coming back from the server. Also, this is my first time here D: so if I didn't format something right or if my code snippets aren't coming over highlighted right let me know and I'll do my best to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

try closing the underlying connection by closing the Closable instance that you get.

```
CloseableHttpResponse resp = ApiCommunicator.getHttpClient().execute(post);
try {
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
       resp.close();
    }
```

Comment: The lack of a close isn't the issue. That particular request never gets past the "Connecting to gamecdnorigin.alliances.commandandconquer.com/212.100.228.211:443" stage. I need to add the close statement there, yes, but I don't believe that is my problem right now.

Comment: I am not familiar with curl so i will stop here as i can't see how to compare the two outputs. what i will suggest though is to use a tool, for example "wireshark" and record the requests made from curl and from java. then, you can compare them to see what actually is being sent in each. you might discover differences, etc in the strings which might also cause the server to refuse the connection from the java side.

Comment: I have been using Wireshark to check the connections made by both the cURL request and the request sent out of Java, but the only difference between the two appears to be that the Java-sent one ends with a connection reset from the server. Now, I don't have a lot of experience working with Wireshark (save for a small stint interning with a local IT group a while back) so it's quite possible that I'm misreading the output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running your java client with the command line option -Djavax.net.debug=ssl as this will give you more (but cryptic) insight into the SSL handshake. That should illuminate the underlying connection troubles, but it might take a while to understand the details that this debug log will output. http://www.smartjava.org/content/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors provides a very nice, detailed discussion of the SSL handshake.

It seems plausible that your HTTPClient does not have a well defined SSLContext. You could explore using some of these options to create it.

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createDefault();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory).build();
```

Note that you can also create custom SSLContext(s) from SSLContexts.custom() which allows you to add keystore, truststore, and to specify using TLS.